# How to clone an object that was declared as it's abstract superclass?

Tags: java, clone, instantiation, copy-constructor

I have a method that gets an abstract class as an argument, for the purpose of polymorphism.
But inside the method i want to return a copy of the actual object been made.

Example:

```
//Animal is an abstract class
public Animal findAndClone(Animal[] zoo){
  for (Animal a:zoo)
    //find some animal...
    return new Animal(a) //cant instantiate an abstract class 
}
```

I tried using a copy-constructor as seen above, but it can't instantiate an abstract.
I thought of defining a `clone()` in the base class but I'm encountering the same problem in the base class.
How to do this right?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to rely on the [dodgy `Object.clone` method](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html), you better create an abstract `copy` method in `Animal` and make sure all subclasses override it properly.

```
abstract class Animal {
    ...
    // Needs to be implemented by subclasses. A Dog returns a Dog, etc...
    public abstract Animal copy();
    ...
}
```

and then instead of doing

```
return new Animal(a);
```

you do

```
return a.copy();
```

Comment: All sub-classes can copy the same as all properties defined in the base-class, the difference is in a definition of some methods, so there is no point to write in every sub-class a copy\clone method that is the same for all. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately that doesn't help you. You still have to follow my suggestion. What you *could* do is to create a helper method in `Animal` which says `copyAnimalMembers` or so, which does this work, which you call in `Dog.copy`, `Cat.copy` and so on. That would save you from copying pasting code in all subclasses.